# How can i use same id for more than one radio buttons?

Tags: html

This is the code which i am using on my page

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="som" value="0">
    <label for="som">Venta</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="som" value="1">
    <label for="som">Aliquera</label>
</li>
```

### css

```
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}
.tabs {
    width: 95%;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.tabs li{
    float: left;
    border:1px solid #006699;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    border-bottom:none;
    width:31%;
    background-color:#EDF6FA;
}
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    color: #08C;

    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.tabs label:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

The above code works only when I use different id for each input `type="radio"` (example if I use `id="som2"` and `<label for="som2">` in second `<li>` it works for checked attribute) but I want this to work when id's are same please help me in this.

The link when I use different id's:http://jsfiddle.net/3PTJf/.

But I want this to work like this link:[using same id's](http://jsfiddle.net/mP6SZ/)  when I use same id's

Comment: You can't, IDs are unique.

Comment: NO you can't and you shouldn't!

Comment: If you use same id at multiple place, it will work only for first element with that Id.

Answer (score 3):

> How can i use same id for more than one radio buttons?

By convention, id is unique identificator - **it has to be unique within whole page**. In other words, one id per one element so two elements shouldn't, couldn't, musn't have same id.

You can check these threads for more information:

- [Why must the ID attribute be unique on each page?](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm)
- [Class vs. ID](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/qt/tipcssclassvsid.htm)

**Note:** If you want to use same style(s) for more elements, consider an usage of classes instead of ids.

Comment: One of each id per page.

Comment: We have used same id and in data base we use value attribute to retrieves data the results are displaying depending on values  not on ids

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an identificator for multiple items on the same page you should use classes. And if you want to set a different property for one element from those you can add an ID too. And in css you can select the item like .something#idofsomething . This will affect only the element which got class="something" id="idofsomething"